# How can I put equation number both on the left and on the right?

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

I know `\documentclass[leqno]` will put equation number on the left.

I'd like the number to show twice : on the left and on the right

---

### Added to the original question

A basic MWE based on a suggestion in the comments, but it's not working. The equation numbers need to be the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
&& E = mc^2 &&(\theequation) 
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use flalign and `(\theequation)`.

Answer (score 2):

The follow example redefines the way the *tag* is set, adding it to both sides:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{%
  \hbox {\m@th \normalfont #1}% Regular (right-hand tag)
  \rlap{\hskip-\displaywidth \m@th \normalfont #1}% Left-hand tag
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= d
\end{align}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The tag is set using `\maketag@@@`, which is updated to add the left-hand tag using a zero-width `r`ight over`lap`.